# GIS SDK for Android

Tags: android, sdk

Im looking a gis sdk for android with these abilities:

- open source or free to use (consider it if you know one)
- can read and write shape files
- can use scalable vector graphics (svg) (optional)
- can show custom icons, lines and text on map
- can calculate distance between two points.

Is there an SDK like this?

Comment: QGIS for Android SDK https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Android